# Вывод атрибута вес в карточке товара в модуле Рекомендуемые (OpenCart)

Tags: opencart, ocstore

Собственно, хочу вывести дополнительные атрибуты товара в модуле рекомендуемые (например вес).

Нашел информацию как это сделать - https://di-grand.com/blog/opencart/2496-opencart-2-0-vyvod-atributov-vesa-na-glavnoj-v-kategorii-v-produkte.html

Что сделал я - в файл featured.tpl по пути OSPanel\domains\pinka.ru\catalog\view\theme\default\template\extension\module

вставил следующий код:

```
<?php if($product['weight'] > 0) { ?>
    <div class="weight">
        <span>Вес:</span> <?php echo $product_info['weight']; ?>гр.
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

в файл featured.php по пути C:\OSPanel\domains\pinka.ru\catalog\controller\extension\module

вставил строку

```
'weight'      => round($product_info['weight'], 2),
```

в блок

```
$data['products'][] = array(
                        'product_id'  => $product_info['product_id'],
                        'thumb'       => $image,
                        'name'        => $product_info['name'],
                        'weight'      => round($product_info['weight'], 2),
                        'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
                        'price'       => $price,
                        'special'     => $special,
                        'tax'         => $tax,
                        'rating'      => $rating,
                        'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id'])
                    );
```

Ошибка

Notice: Undefined index: weight in C:\OSPanel\domains\pinka.ru\catalog\view\theme\default\template\extension\module\featured.tpl on line 22

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уточните версию opencart

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что у вас где-то закралась ошибка:

```
<?php if($product['weight'] > 0) { ?>
    <div class="weight">
        <span>Вес:</span> <?php echo $product_info['weight']; ?>гр.
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Вы тут проверяйте `$product['weight']`, а потом выводите `$product_info['weight']`. Я так думаю, что вам надо проверять `$product_info`.

А вообще код должен быть таким примерно:

```
<?php if ($weight) { ?>
    <div class="weight">
        <span>Вес:</span> <?php echo $weight; ?>гр.
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь получить значение **weight** для продукта внутри цикла `foreach(products as $product)` на фронте, но вызываете внутреннюю переменную(array) контроллера `$product_info`.

Дальше сами ;)